# Handling Required Nullable Properties in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core, I'm using the `[Required]` attribute on certain nullable properties of my model. I want these properties to always be supplied in the incoming JSON, even if their value is null. So, if a property is omitted from the JSON payload, it should be treated as a validation error, but if the property is provided with a null value, it should be considered valid.

For example, given the model:

```
public class SampleModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The following JSON should be valid:

```
{
    "SomeProperty": null
}
```

But this should be invalid due to the omission of SomeProperty:

```
{}
```

Looks like using the `[Required]` attribute is not the way, since it's validating the the property value is not null.
I can write my own model validation that will validate the model using recursion & reflection but that does not seems the right way to handle this.

What's the best and simplest way to achieve this behavior in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Is there a reason you need it present even if it may be set to `null`? If you allow it to be omitted, you can save on transmitted bytes. (Which is the thought behind making this behavior default, but doesn't need to make sense everywhere)

Comment: continuing my example, `SomeProperty` is a nullable configuration property in my application. If I will not require, it will be set to null during the binding, and I will not be able to figure if it was supplied as null, or set to null because it was missing.

Comment: I don't get the difference. If it is omitted despite _having_ a value then _that_ is an error the client needs to fix. But that will occur regardless of if you accept an omitted prop and take it for null or force the prop and client sets it null by mistake.

Comment: Forcing it will make the client decide what he wants to do with that property, if he set it to null by mistake, then that's his problem. I rather avoid the case where omitting it will have an implicit effect.

Comment: Ok. In that case ... you might need to tap into the (de)serialization process. Maybe newtonsoft's json schema validation could do the trick, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,you may add  `[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.AllowNull)]` attribute on your entity

and call `builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()`;in your program.cs:

the entity :

```
[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.AllowNull)]
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string? Prop1 { get; set;}

    public string? Prop2 { get; set;}

    public string? Prop3 { get; set;}
}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]